# Does Visual Studio compile test classes into an assembly?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

Does Visual Studio compile classes marked with test attributes into an assembly? Suppose this assembly has internal classes that could benefit from unit test coverage.

Comment: A bit of background for those curious:

I write many different kinds of tests in my program. I've written a library that has some internal classes that shouldn't be accessed individually because it wouldn't make sense- they're just cogs in the machine. But by that nature, they can't be unit tested from another project either.

I like to keep my tests and the tested code separate, and I don't like extra stuff like this dangling if I can help it. Reducing the number of classes visible to the user can help them pick the right one for the task they wish to accomplish.

Comment: Everything in your comment should be in the question, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. I didn't feel it was relevant to the question.

Comment: Yes, please use the [edit] link to update your question

Comment: Are you saying that you have test classes in the same project as your internal classes, and you are wondering if during compilation if those test classes are compiled? Or are you talking about a separate test project altogether?

Comment: I *didn't* want to include tests in my main assembly if I didn't have to, so I asked this in case there was no other way just to see if it was an issue in the output. If the classes show up, I would write that into the Readme. If they didn't, it's a non-issue for users (but not a win on the code side, really)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you've got a separate test project, yes that's really just another class library project. (If you're expecting VS to split classes from a single project into "test" and "non-test" assemblies, then the answer is no... and you shouldn't do that :)

Unit testing internal classes is entirely reasonable - and is by far the most important reason for [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute). You make your production internal classes visible to your test project, and then you can test them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
More specifically, Visual Studio takes the classes contained within a test project and generates a DLL via the compilation process.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the question, it seems he has test classes embedded in the non-test project.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a separate test project, it will get compiled into a different assembly from the main project. Often, the test project just gets ignored when you deploy so the client will never see it. One good way to wrap your mind around it is to try:

```
> vstest.console MyTestProject\bin\Debug\MyTestProject.dll
```

The test runner only picks up the test assembly.